# condition not working properly in google map javaScript for marker

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, csv, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot different markers on google maps taking data from a csv file. I am using parsecsv-0.4.3-beta to read the csv. Everything is working just fine except when I compare two fields and try to change the marker according to that. It is changing the marker but for few fields it's giving the wrong marker. I think I have made some mistake in the condition.

```
<?php
# include parseCSV class.
require_once('../parsecsv.lib.php');
# create new parseCSV object.
$csv = new parseCSV();
# Parse '_books.csv' using automatic delimiter detection...
$csv->auto('latlang.csv');
# ...or if you know the delimiter, set the delimiter character
# if its not the default comma...
// $csv->delimiter = "\t";   # tab delimited
# ...and then use the parse() function.
// $csv->parse('_books.csv');
//print_r ($csv->data);
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCWPvg5SpuPqRnY0Ldhlz2QhLgrCqnlYFM&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = <?php print json_encode($csv->data); ?>;
    window.onload = function () {
        LoadMap();
    }
    function LoadMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[1].Latitude, markers[1].Longtitude),
            zoom: 7,
            styles: [{"stylers": [{ "saturation": -100 }]}],
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

        //Create and open InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longtitude);
            var image1 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
            var image2 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
            **if (data.CL < data.DL) {
                var image = image2;
            }else {
                var image = image1;
            };**

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.Station,
                icon:image,
            });
            //Attach click event to the marker.
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + "<p>" + "<b>Station:</b> " + data.Station + "<br>"+ "CL:" + data.CL + "<br>" + "<b>River Name: </b>" + data.RiverName + "<br>" + "<b>DL(mPWD): </b>" + data.DL +"<br>" + "<b>HRWL(mPWD):</b> "+ data.HRWL +"</p>"+"</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 900px; height: 500px">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample of the csv file:

[image: csv file sample]

In most cases it shows the right marker... some markers do not meet the condition.

Comment: which condition is not met.

Comment: I think your code is right, as you are getting two red markers and rest are blue markers, which is right according to your logic and your data in your CSV. Is there any thing which I missed please elaborate.

Comment: According to my condition if DL is greater then CL it is suppose to be red but in few markers its not meeting the conditions. instead of red its showing blue for few markers. its kinda weird..

Comment: http://vamphim.com/marker.php  check last 4 markers  on the bottom for station Dohazari .  the values are given on description.

Comment: what is station name and river name for which it should be red and it is showing blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add these lines in your code:

```
data.CL = Number(data.CL);
data.DL = Number(data.DL);
if (data.CL < data.DL) {
    var image = image2;
}else {
    var image = image1;
};
```

Your data was coming in string, but we are using < operator to check that so in some case it might fail. Better to convert and then check for greater or less.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its really appreciated. nice thing to learn. Its Working now. cheers!